# return the sum of a field and all the rows using mysql

Tags: mysql

im having a table

```
id      admission       amount          paid_date 

12      0001            1750            2012-09-23
13      0002            1750            2012-09-23
14      0010            1750            2012-09-23
```

i used the below query

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(amount) ) 
FROM gains
WHERE  `paid_date`  LIKE '%2012-09-23%'
ORDER BY `paid_date`
```

but my output is

```
id      admission       amount          paid_date     (SELECT SUM(amount) ) 

12      0001            1750            2012-09-23          5250
```

is it possible to get all 3 records and the sum of the amount separately using one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
      (SELECT SUM(amount) 
       FROM gains
       WHERE  `paid_date` LIKE '%2012-09-23%') as sum_amount
FROM gains
WHERE  `paid_date`  LIKE '%2012-09-23%'
group by admission
ORDER BY `paid_date`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(amount) ) 
FROM gains
WHERE  `paid_date`  LIKE '%2012-09-23%'
GROUP BY admission
```